How to use IntentParameterDependency.init(_:_:)?
I'm working on adding AppIntents to an iOS app written in Swift.
When an EntityQuery has a parameter dependency, Apple recommends to use
@IntentParameterDependency<OrderSoup>(
    \.$quantity
)
var orderSoup

which works just fine. If an entity is a parameter in multiple intents, adding a singular IntentParameterDependency for each intent gets messy very quickly.
According to the Documentation, IntentParameterDependancy has initializers for up to 15 Intent/KeyPath pairs. The initializer looks like this:
convenience init<V0, P0, V1, P1>(
    _ k0: KeyPath<Intent, P0>,
    _ k1: KeyPath<Intent, P1>
) where V0 : _IntentValue, V0 : Sendable, P0 : IntentParameter<V0>, V1 : _IntentValue, V1 : Sendable, P1 : IntentParameter<V1>

I tried to use this initializer similarly to how I would for one KeyPath:
@IntentParameterDependency<OrderSoup, ReturnSoup>(
    \OrderSoup.$quantity,
    \ReturnSoup.$quantity
)
var soup

But the compiler complains Generic type 'IntentParameterDependency' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1).
What is the correct syntax to use this with multiple intents?

IntentParameterDependency is only for one intent. You can specify multiple key paths of the same intent, but that's it.
